# How I should to modify at my typescript code?

Tags: typescript

I write a code following a tutorial. In tutorial, this code is functional, but for me not and I don't understand why. I wrote something wrong here?

```
abstract class Car {
    public description: string;
    public getDescription(): string {
        return this.description;
    }
    public abstract cost(): number;
}
class ModelS extends Car {
    public description = "Model S";
    public cost(): number {
        return 73000;
    }
}
class ModelX extends Car {
    public description = "Model X";
    public cost(): number {
        return 77000;
    }
}
abstract class CarOptions extends Car {
    decoratedCar: Car;
    public abstract getDescription(): string;
    public abstract cost(): number;
}
class EnhancedAutoPilot extends CarOptions {
    decoratedCar: Car;
    constructor(car: Car) {
        super();
        this.decoratedCar = car;
    }
    public getDescription(): string {
        return this.decoratedCar.getDescription() + ', Enhanced AutoPilot';
    }
    public cost(): number {
        return this.decoratedCar.cost() + 5000;
    }
}
class RearFacingSeats extends CarOptions {
    decoratedCar: Car;
    constructor(car: Car) {
        super();
        this.decoratedCar = car;
    }
    public getDescription(): string {
        return this.decoratedCar.getDescription() + ', Rear facing seats';
    }
    public cost(): number {
        return this.decoratedCar.cost() + 4000;
    }
}
let myTesla = new ModelS();
myTesla = new RearFacingSeats(myTesla);
console.log(myTesla.cost());
console.log(myTesla.getDescription());
```

This is my code, and when I try to write in terminal **tsc decorator.ts**, I have errors there for this row:
**myTesla = new RearFacingSeats(myTesla);**

I don't understand what I should to modify. And I don't understand what means that errors. Why I can't run this in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

When you declared the `myTesla` variable, you implicitly gave it a type of ModelS. Then you go ahead to assign the value of `new RearFacingSeats(myTesla)` to it which is of type `RearFacingSeats`. That gives an error when you run `tsc`.

What should happen is:

```
let myTesla = new RearFacingSeats(new ModelS());
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and everything seems fine as `myTesla` variable has a type of `ModelS` which in fact is inherited from `Car` one. Due to that, you can pass any Car-inherited object to the `RearFacingSeats` constructor without problem.

Which compiler settings do you have? Typescript version?